# GCC -g file format

Tags: gcc, gdb

GCC -g uses the native file format (stabs, COFF, XCOFF, or DWARF). 
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/gcc/Debugging-Options.html

Which format is used on Linux? How can I prove which file format is used?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
readelf --debug-dump ./a.out
```

or similarly

```
readelf --debug-dump ./a.out | grep -i dwarf
```